# What is a reputable introductory text for the study of linguistics?

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking to study linguistics. Could someone recommend a reputable introductory text for the study of linguistics?

Comment: The best textbook I know of it Bolinger's _Aspects of Language_, **2ⁿᵈ** edition. It's been out of print for years. I wouldn't really recommend a text; solving problems is how one learns linguistics. I can offer the textbooks I used in teaching Intro Ling, which are mostly handouts and problems; they're around 100p each. [Part 1](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart1.pdf) covers morphology, phonetics, and phonology (not all of it, of course), and [Part 2](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart2.pdf) covers syntax, semantics, and pragmatics, plus selected short subjects.

Comment: If you're a true beginner then, in general, I wouldn't suggest a textbook as, with few exceptions, they are large, complicated, and boring to read. Not great for motivation. I would suggest [The Language Instinct](http://www.amzn.com/0061336467) by Steven Pinker. It's pop-linguistics but it's short, easy to read, and introduces a lot of basic concepts. If you want something more in-depth you can look into an online course like [this one on MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/24-900-introduction-to-linguistics-spring-2004/index.htm)

Comment: Nice. I just found Bolinger's for about $5 on Amazon marketplace. Thank you for the recommendation.